# How to help inexperienced programmers who just can't get it

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users

I sometimes try to answer questions and help people who clearly were very inexperienced programmers. It seems to happen to me regularly, maybe because I answer questions in tags popular with beginners (c#, SQL, Android).

Those questions are valid, even if not worded in the best way and rather simple. Still, I want to help people to learn.

The problem is that after giving an answer, additional explanation, comments, etc,  many times those people still don't get it. They probably just lack knowledge to such extend that teaching them through SO is a bit hopeless. It's frustrating for them and for me. Sometimes English is also a problem.

What can be done in those situations? What is the best course of action that matches how SO works?

Clarification

I'm talking about the cases where the question is fairly good but an inexperienced user can't understand the concepts behind the answer.  Not about users who don't know how to use SO.

Comment: You may find some related discussion here: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and [How to help hapless newbies become better SO users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24685/how-to-help-hapless-newbies-become-better-so-users) and [What are the most effective ways to guide new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167452/what-are-the-most-effective-ways-to-guide-new-users)

Comment: Thanks. I'm talking about the cases where the question is fairly good but an inexperienced user can't understand the concepts behind the answer.

Comment: What you can suggest is to ask them to read the best resources which you have experienced. Also share site URL's. Ask to start with basics.

Comment: qv [Learning to fish one painful question at a time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105658)

Comment: Especially when you encounter a question like: *I got this WordPress website and I want to integrate this jQuery plugin but it's not working....* you know you might as well reply in [insert here any foreign hard to learn language]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OP should address a specific programming issue, if he needs more than that he should go and read some books rather then covering an entire topic in Q&A post.

A question isn't 1X1 discussion. So even if the OP doesn't get it, many users from the community will if your answer is good.

Comment: very valid point that it's not 1 to 1 discussion and other people may and will benefit from an answer, however now the answered may possibly get dragged into a chameleon case. I think it's worth knowing [Exit strategies for chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)